# Upgrading react native to 0.49.0-rc.5

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babeljs

Trying to upgrade my rn project to react native : 0.49.0-rc.5 and enzyme 3, all the tests works fine but babel throws transformation errors when running the packager.

[image]This is the Error

`bundling failed: Error: require() must have a single string literal argument`

Regarding the stack : 
`"react": "^16.0.0-beta.5",`
`"react-native": "^0.49.0-rc.5",`
`"enzyme": "^3.0.0"`

And 
`Node :  8.5`

Comment: You can downgrade babel and check if it works

Comment: I could get this working but had to comment out the line no : 1830 from moment.js

`require('./locale/' + name);`

Answer (score 4):

With React 0.49.0-rc.5, they have updated the metro bundler which does not support dynamic imports as in `require('./locale/' + name);` can no longer work and would throw error while bundling.

Most of the packages which does this kind of dynamic imports have fixed their code for the latest react native 
EX: Realm (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6391) and in my case it was moment.js which does dynamic imports and they need to fix this.

Comment: Hey Grub , at the moment did not upgrade as moment is still havent resolved this. Check the progress here : https://github.com/moment/moment/pull/4187#issuecomment-334960031